# Limit laws for random matrix products covergence

Tags: random-matrices, limits-and-convergence

I'm trying to understand Theorem 1.1 in [Limit laws for random matrix products](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.03698.pdf).
It states that a specific product of random matrices converges to a set matrix but I don't know which kind of convergence of random variables is meant here. Is it almost sure or even sure convergence?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 1.1 does not refer to a probabilistic limit, it holds elementwise for any given series of matrices that satisfies the conditions stated in the theorem.